# Why is Safari rendering my border image wrong?

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari

I have a div with a CSS `border-image`:

```css
.bc-test-labels {
  border-top: 30px solid black;
  border-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, transparent 20px, black 20px, black 30px, transparent 30px, transparent 50px) 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bc-test-labels">
  <br>
</div>
```

In Chrome on macOS, where I do most of my testing it looks as expected:

[image]

And the same for Firefox:

[image]

It also works in Edge - and even Internet Explorer 11. Unfortunately, on both Desktop and iOS Safari, it renders like this:

[image]

For some reason, the `border-image` is also rendered on the bottom, left and and right.

Looking in the Web Inspector, we can see a 3px border around the entire `<div>`, and the 30px border at the top:

[image]

Under Styles -> Visual -> Background -> Border section we can see that the top has the designated style and height, and that Left, Right and Bottom have `style:none`:

[image]
[image]

Adding `border: 0px` as the first line of the CSS definition fixes this, but it's a little annoying it is needed.

Why is Safari rendering all the borders with my image, not just the one I specified?